# Simplify .net core web api design complexity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

This is a design related problem.

I have a legacy application in asp.net webforms which have 3 kind of users: Admin, Customer and Provider, which access multiple services like Product, Account, Sale, Purchase etc. All these 3 users share same set of class libraries for services, logic and database until now. And the deployment is single for all 3 users.

Now we are migrating this into .net core web api + angular. And I am thinking about the options. Till now I have figured out this is the best for our application:

1. Create separate web api for Admin, Customer and Provider. Then for any changes in Admin, the deployment will not impact Customer.
   But the problem with this approach is the class libraries will be duplicated. Some common methods will be duplicated.

Is there any alternative/good approach for this?

Comment: What do you mean class libraries will be duplicated? Class library is a project and you can share it with multiple project. You can have two different solution with e.g. asp.net core project that share single class library project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is too large, so I decided to add another answer.
To **migrate your monolithic** app into **Microservice** or **Macroservice** it should be better to follow below steps:

1. **Identify all component groups**, which means you should decompose your application into several small projects, in your example, they would be **AdminPeoject**, **CustomerProject**, and **ProviderProject**.
2. then define **several endpoints** and **APIs** for all your data access scenario. for example if you need to **access** or **manipulate** data located in **AdminProject** and your request source is other project, you would have an API for this purpose in your AdminProject, and from now on every request which related to data manipulation in AdminProject should be done by these APIs.
3. In the next step, every project should be **deployable** and **independent** of the deployment of other projects.
4. If your system is not complex, it does not need to migrate your **Macroservice** into Microservice because it will add so many **complexities** to your project.
5. it's better to use a **single datastore**. after a while, if there is a need for separation, you just need to separate the data stores.

Answer (score 1):

The separation of projects can be beneficial in case of :

1. **updating** one project don't impact the others
2. **release cycle** can be very small in this approach which obviously results in faster development and deployment
3. but if you just want to separate your project and they still have a single datastore, this architecture is a **Macroservice architecture** and the communication between micros should be done by APIs
4. for your **shared code**, you can define a **Nuget package** and every project can add it into their project to **prevent repetitive code**

Comment: Great. First two things makes sense to me. Shall I go for microservices but the application is not so big and complex. And I doubt 3 and 4 point will impact the performance of the application and complexity will increase.

Comment: Is there any considerations/ best practices/ important things I have to take care of while migrating? So that migration is smooth.

Comment: [You may find this video useful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeHg4b_RyjM). It's about migrating a monolithic into microservices.